# How do I add an iscsi target to a windows initiator through stock cmd?

Tags: windows, networking, iscsi, windows-command-prompt

I have many Windows Servers that need to run headless but I need to add many iscsi targets to each of the Windows hosts.

I already have the iscsi target setup and have access to IP address of where to query targets as well as the IQN's of the targets.

I need to instruct the Windows hosts, and only through `cmd` or programs native to `cmd`, to add the target to the initiator.

Is this possible?  If so, how would I do this?

Comment: Give this a read and let us know if it helps you come up with something via the command line to complete what you're asking whether or not is possible. Please share your final result that works or else let us know what you come up with that you cannot get to work. . .http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2012/02/27/connecting-to-an-iscsi-san-using-command-line-options-on-hyper-v-server-amp-server-core.aspx

Comment: That for sure puts me onto the correct track.  Thank you very much for the link.

Comment: Great, when you find the actual answer, go ahead and add it as your own answer to potentially help others find the answer quicker in the future.  Otherwise, post what you have and try that you have issues with as an edit on your question.

Comment: Will post the solution once I have successfully performed the commands..  Technical issues currently, more to come.